# AssetsLibrary, how to enumerate all photos?

Tags: objective-c, ios, alassetslibrary, alasset

Is there better way to enumerate all photos on the device than this one?

**for each** asset group do this ...

```
[currentGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) 
     {         
         if(result == nil) 
         {
             return;
         }
         // add the asset
     }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant ALAssetsGroupAll is used for enumerating groups of certain or all types.  It's used when enumerating the library fishing for groups.  But the only way to get all photos, or any type of asset for that matter is to enumerate as you've already coded.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this once by enumerating the group `ALAssetsGroupLibrary`, which contains all the images in the other groups.

Comment: This is wrong solution i think, To enumerate all you much better is to use this enumerate *ALAssetsGroupAll*

Comment: The advantage of using `ALAssetsGroupLibrary` is that you don't get any duplicates, for images that belong to multiple groups.

Comment: I do not exactly remember, but i had problems enumeration photos using  ALAssetsGroupLibrary